# Overlay image and plot with irregular sampling in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I have data coming from a simulation where the results are a function of 2 parameters, `xval` and `yval`. The sampling of `yval` is regular, but the sampling of `xval` is irregular.

I have the result of the simulation for each combination of `xval` and `yval` pairs, and I can plot the results with a contour plot. Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

xval = np.array([ 10,  15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 250, 500])
yval = np.array([ 6, 12, 16, 22, 26, 32, 38, 42, 48, 52, 58, 62, 68, 74, 78, 84, 88, 94])

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xval, yval)
sim = np.exp(-(xx/20))   # very deterministic simulation!

levels = np.sort(sim.mean(axis=0))

plt.clf()
plt.contour(xval, yval, sim, colors='k', vmin=1e-10, vmax=sim.max(), levels=levels)
```

I have on purpose set the levels of the contours to the values of the simulation. Here is the result:

[image]

Now I would like to overlay the `sim` array on this contour plot as an image. I have used the following command:

```
plt.imshow(sim, interpolation='nearest', origin=1, aspect='auto', vmin=1e-10, vmax=sim.max(),
           extent=(xval.min(), xval.max(), yval.min(), yval.max()), norm=colors.LogNorm())
```

And here is the result:

[image]

As you can see the contours and the `sim` data do not match in the plot, although they should. This seems normal because the `imshow` method does not take `xval` and `yval` values as argument, so it does not know at which `(xval,yval)` points the simulation is provided.

Now the question is: how do I manage to have my image data match the contours? Do I need to reinterpolate the `sim` array or is there some other command in `matplotlib` that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html), which expects the x and y coordinates as input.

```
plt.pcolormesh(xx,yy,sim)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

xval = np.array([ 10,  15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 250, 500])
yval = np.array([ 6, 12, 16, 22, 26, 32, 38, 42, 48, 52, 58, 62, 68, 74, 78, 84, 88, 94])

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xval, yval)
sim = np.exp(-(xx/20.))   # very deterministic simulation!

levels = np.sort(sim.mean(axis=0))

plt.contour(xval, yval, sim, colors='k', vmin=1e-10, vmax=sim.max(), levels=levels)

plt.pcolormesh(xx,yy,sim,  vmin=1e-10, vmax=sim.max(), norm=colors.LogNorm())

plt.show()
```

[image]